# Virtualization speed king: intel xeon westmere 5620 vs AMD Magnycour 6134

Tags: performance, vmware-esx, intel, central-processing-unit

two similarly sized 2P systems from HP: 48GB ram, 8x (300gb 15k SAS)
ESX 4.0 is s/w
but choice of AMD 6134 gives 16 cores vs Intel 5620's 8 cores. Both almost at same CPU Clock 2.4 GHz
for VM workloads of medium size which is best bang for buck/perf?
workloads : mostly Windows VM guests
-- thx in adv

Comment: if thats a single 15k sas then it won't matter what cpu's you have you'll more then likely run out of iops before cpu!

Comment: sorry its 300GB x 8 disks

Comment: What are the VM guess doing? DBs? Data mining? VDI? Idle?

Comment: With esxi r u going to have a datacenter os license? I'm really wishing that you could purchase these things with a single proc (thus only paying for a single datacenter license) and not dual since the current cpu's are fast enough anyway for most things (like I said its iops then ram that count most).  And in this case (single proc) I'd go for the amd since it has more cores,  my .00001 cents worth

Comment: VM spread: 25% idle, 50% medium load (800Mhz CPU) and rest heavy CPU (1200Mhz) and IOPS. total 22 VMs in a box.
what about license? AFAIK Vsphere Std supports upto 2P with 6 cores each. what is additional cost of license for 8+8 cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're talking DL385 G7 vs. DL380 G7 right?

The most important question you need to ask is if this is to be part of an existing or future DRS cluster - if so then the manufacturer needs to match across the cluster so that should override any speed gain or loss.

If you could ONLY buy one or the other of these two chips I'd go for the AMD, simply because 16 full cores (i.e. 2 x 8 in the 6134) will give you overall better performance than the 5620's 8 full cores plus hyperthreading - simply because not every task will make best use of threading. Plus the 385 has 24 DIMM sockets over the 380's 18. That said if I had a choice I'd go for the 12-core 6172 chips to be honest, their power-per-watt and price is pretty compelling.

Oh and the 6134 is 2.3Ghz by the way.

NB: - It's worth you knowing that I'm a known Intel advocate but I'm more than happy to recommend AMD here.

Comment: oh fantastic answer and clarity. BTW i was comparing a DL165G7 and ML350G6....since a tower chasis ML is cheaper than DL by 1K. There are no plans for DRS cluster.

Comment: I'm a BL-guy through and through so sorry I'd forgotten about that ML - in fact it's a great machine - wish I had a need for one really - I keep looking for reasons to use SLs but no luck just yet.